# catalog only: disable purchase

Tags: catalog

it there a setting to make my mercado website catalog only, ie. disable purchasing of all products. The site is a music publisher who doesn't want to sell items directly to customers, but rather just want to show a listing of available items.

Comment: No you can only hide wisslist and add to comaper from backend. But for add to cart we have to code in few files.

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to do that -- sure you can reduce inventory sizes to zero and enable stockless products, but then it just looks, well, badly managed.

If you want to achieve what you wanted to do you need to modify templates --- disable "add to cart" buttons, quantity selection and so on. You probably also want to disable my account and login, checkout, wish list and few other things, but all this requires some knowledge about Magento development.